# Segmentation Fault when using malloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I think I've got everything fixed now.  I made the mistake of incrementing the environ variable instead of treating it like an array and iterating across it.  The following is what I have now and it should be good to go.

```
extern char **environ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // determine number of environment variables
    int n = 0;
    char *c = NULL;
    while ((c = environ[n++]) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", c);
    }
    printf("%s\n%d\n\n", c, n);

    // allocate array to store character pointers to environment array
    char **new_c;
    printf("This prints\n");
    if ((new_c = malloc(n * sizeof(*c))) == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("This prints now too\n");
    free(c);

    // sort array of character pointers

    // parse each environment variable and output

    exit(0);
}
```

---

To start, I've read through a couple dozen malloc & segmentation fault questions on here and none seem to be the same as mine.  That being said, if this is a duplicate question would you mine pointing me to the solution?

Hi all, I'm having a problem using malloc.  I compiled and ran my program once and malloc worked.  I then began filling in more code to solve the problem and since that first run I have received a Segmentation Fault.  Below is my code in it's last working state (still giving a seg fault error though):

```
extern char **environ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // determine number of environment variables
    int n = 0;
    char *c = *environ;
    while ((c = *environ++) != NULL) {
        n++;
        printf("%s\n", c);
    }
    printf("%s\n%d\n\n", c, n);

    // allocate array to store character pointers to environment array
    printf("This prints\n");
    if ((c = malloc((size_t) n)) == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to allocate memory\n");
    }
    printf("This does not print\n");
    free(c);

    // sort array of character pointers

    // parse each environment variable and output

    exit(0);
}
```

The program is supposed to allocate memory for a char array that will then be used to sort, parse, and print the name-value or value-name pairs depending on what the FORMAT value is set to.  The first loop works and iterates through the environ variable and prints out each name-value pair.  The two printf statements I included state what I see in the terminal.  Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Also, I have tried using the following malloc lines:

```
char *new_c = malloc((size_t) n);
char *new_c = malloc(n);
char *new_c = malloc(1);
char *new_c = malloc(sizeof(n));
int *ptr = malloc((size_t) n);
```

There are probably a few others I tried but I'm still baffled.  There are so few lines of code that I'm not sure how I could be messing anything up this early on.  Also, for giggles here's what I get when I use free in the terminal (showing I have memory available):

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3036836     1404340      902852      104712      729644     1491248
Swap:             0           0           0
```

I've also tried calling malloc outside of the if statement as such:

```
c = malloc((size_t) n);
if (c == NULL) {
    perror("Unable to allocate memory\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are modifying the global `environ`:

```
while ((c = *environ++) != NULL) {
```

After the while loop, `environ` points to uninitialized memory.

`malloc()` looks for some environment variables which can modify its behaviour and is now dereferencing a pointer to uninitialized memory.
Use this:

```
int i = 0;
while ((c = environ[i++]) != NULL) {
```

This should fix the segmentation fault.

Comment: Good, call, this was the issue I was working on next.  Now I'm not getting a segmentation fault, but the this statement does not print out:

    printf("This does not print\n");

Comment: @ZSButcher Well, it should, I do not see a reason why not. Can you show the complete modified code?

Comment: I change the conditions of the if statement to != by mistake.  Everything seems to be working now.  Thanks for the good eye!

Answer (score 1):

Two things with this:

```
if ((c = malloc((size_t) n)) == NULL) {
    perror("Unable to allocate memory\n");
}
```

You are allocating `n` bytes, here. It sounds like you want to allocate space for `n` pointers to `char`, so you should replace with:

```
malloc(n * sizeof(char *))
```

If this is indeed what you're trying to do, then `c` should be `char **`, not `char *`, and better still would be:

```
c = malloc(n * sizeof *c)
```

Incidentally, you appear to be using `c` for two completely different things. It's generally better not to do this with variables - since it makes your program harder to understand - and instead to use one variable to loop through to print your environment variables, and a different one to store your dynamically allocated array.

Also, you call `perror()` if `malloc()` fails, but then you just continue right on with your program as if there was no error. You should actually respond to a failure of this nature, if nothing else by calling `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` after reporting it.

Comment: Allocating `n*sizeof(char *)` to a `char *` . Maybe I am wrong but I doubt OP wants this .

Comment: I just replaced my malloc with yours and I'm still getting the Segmentation Fault.  I also put the exit call in there, thanks for catching that.